# Make two DIVs fill their parent when one of them is on the bottom

Tags: css, html, css-float

I have two DIVs inside one DIV. One of the DIVs is floated left, and so, the other div is to fill outer window.
If I enlarge or shrink the outer DIV I want inside DIVs to fill outer DIV in any case. 
The sample code:

```
<div id="main_container">
    <div id="left_container"></div>
    <div id="right_container"></div>
</div>​
```

and CSS rules are

```
#main_container {
    border: 1px ridge blue;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 93%;
}

#left_container{
    margin: 10px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-width: 200px;
}

#right_container{
    margin: 10px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid magenta;
    min-width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

​

Here is the [jsfiddle code.](http://jsfiddle.net/zd6jL/4/)

Reize the html window, you will see *red* one is not filling it when the other is on the bottom.

Edit: To clarify, I added images

[image: This is OK]

[image: This is not OK]

Comment: I still don't understand how it gets adjusted, even though the right is not floated.

Comment: Is this what you need [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/zd6jL/17/)

Comment: @Praveen Kumar, Wow you're right. I edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 441px) {
    #left_container{
        float: none;
    }
}
```

`441px` just an example (two blocks `min-width` + side `margins` + `border` - 1).

Comment: Yes. I would like to see another method but for now I can't find one...

You got static (px) sizes, why media-queries aren't good for you?

Comment: Conditional comments + [polyfill](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) and it works in ie6+

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
width: 98%;
```

(Adjust as necessary)

To #left_container and #right_container

Answer (score 0):

#### Give `min-width` to the main div.

```
#main_container {
    border: 1px ridge blue;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 93%;
    min-width: 400px;
}
```